# Are app-based reward programs halal?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

There is an app called [Giftiz](http://www.giftiz.com/) which rewards you with points for downloading apps. In order to get the points, you just have to launch the app or pass a certain level, get a certain score, etc. My question is this: Is this halal or is it a form of gambling?